# DLL code injection with remote Thread: Where to store DLL filename/location in target process address space?

Tags: c, dll, code-injection, createremotethread

there might be no (useful) answere to this Questions, but whatever.
I want to inject code into an application via DLL code injection.
The plan is:

1. Find the address of the LoadLibrary function in the target process.
2. Write a string with the name/filepath of the DLL i want to load using WriteProcessMemory() somewhere in the target process address space.
3. Start a remote thread using CreateRemoteThread() with the address of LoadLibrary() as entry point and a pointer to the string containing the name/filepath of the DLL to be loaded as the Argument for the LoadLibrary() function.

The problem is at no. 2.
Where in the target process address space do i store the string (without corrupting something)?

If this question has been asked before, feel free to point me there.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`VirtualAllocEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890.aspx) allows you to specify the process in which memory is allocated. You would use this to allocate a block of memory. Note that you cannot write directly to the returned address--it is in a different process. You would write the DLL name via [`WriteProcessMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx).

If you were intending to place your code in `DllMain`, you should not. Windows holds an internal lock while executing `DllMain` and this adds a risk of a deadlock, depending on what you intend to do in your hook code. You could get the address of a function in your DLL and use `CreateRemoteThread` again to run this on a separate thread after the DLL has been loaded.

Rather than implementing all this yourself, I would recommend that you use a library someone has already written, such as [EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/), which supports both managed and unmanaged injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, VirtualAllocEx is what i needed.